# C# Самые оптимальные методы для массивного скачивания?

Tags: c#, torrent

Разрабатываю проект в samp и столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами. Но проект необычен, он имеет свой модпак, который нужно скачать перед тем как зайти на проект, скачивается он с лаунчера. Так как игроков будет не мало 700+, то и скачивать придётся тоже не мало. Из этого исходит вопрос, который указан в шапке этого топика. Я понимаю, что можно купить CDN или какие-нибудь другие дорогие заморочки, но это не совсем подходит. Конкретно я использую метод скачивания торрентом, то есть, есть машина (VDS) на которой запущена раздача, но её как оказалось - не хватает. Так вот, как мне быть со скачиванием? Трафика не хватает (300 мбит). Пока что у меня есть следующие идеи: 1. Ограничение скорости на клиенте исходя из загруженности машины. 2. Реализовать систему очереди в скачивании, где люди будут качать по очереди рядами из нескольких человек. 3. Купить несколько машин (VDS) и направлять клиента скачивать на свободную. Подскажите, есть ли более оптимальные методы скачивания при массивном скачивании.

Comment: Торрент это не просто "Скачать файл с сервера", это P2P сеть, где каждый клиент является сервером. Так что если вы программно позволите людям раздавать то, что они скачали, то скорости будет вполне хватать для всех, правда они должны сидеть на раздаче.

Comment: Объем скаченного какой? Если торрент не вариант, vds дорогой, может рассмотрите такие варианты как Яндекс диск? Если это не поможет, ну поглядите на цены amazon s3

Comment: Объём модпака который скачивается ~4гб.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ для этого надо держать лаунчер запущенным

Comment: @EvgeniyZ скорость отдачи с каждого юзера примерно по 1кб, что очень и очень мало

Comment: Я когда то просто выкладывал моды  на FTP с безлимиткой, но это более 6 лет назад было, Хз как сейчас.

Comment: @tym32167 Об этом я и сказал. Обычно игровые сервера делают так, авторизация и запуск игры идет именно через лаунчер и игрок не может играть без него. Как по мне самый лучший вариант, ибо такое дает еще и возможность без костылей "проверять" целостность данных.

Comment: Мой [старый проект](https://github.com/tym32167/Arma3Launcher) со скачкой по ftp, просто если интересно.

Comment: @self.mercy Такого не может быть, точней может, но для небольшого кол-ва пользователей. У всех есть своя скорость отдачи и она явно не 1кб/с...

Comment: Но в моём случае она именно около 1 кб/с, возможно из-за этого у нас данная проблема.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ всё это тестилось с 10-15 людьми и одновременным скачиванием.

Comment: Значит неверно настроена раздача. Попробуйте любой торрент клиент, запустите там свою раздачу и пусть другие будут качать, каждый новый человек будет качать не только с вас, а со всех тех, кто качает на данный момент (либо скачал и сидит на раздаче).

Answer (score 0):

В коментариях к вопросу написали про ftp и это нужно делать если вы хотите контролировать целостность файлов (MD5(он медленный) или что-то подобное). С ваши онлайном вам нужно  сделать ftp  и открытие ЗБТ(Для того что бы увеличить список сидеров торрента) и после того как участники ЗБТ будут иметь файлы для глобальной раздачи вы сможете запустить довольно мощную torrent раздачу для всех ваших задач.
P.S  это довольно кустарный вариант, но рабочий.